# C# JSON custom serialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Is there a way/library that will allow me to customize JSON serialization similar to GSON custom serializers?

Here is what I'm trying to get:

this object: **KeyValuePair("Age",10) myAge**

will normally get serialized like

*"myAge": {
       "Key": "Age",
       "Value": 10
   }*

whilst I want it to serialize like: *"Age": 10* instead. Any ideas?

Comment: google has been good to me and this should work out: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/SerializationAttributes.html

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First i suggest to use [newton json dll](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx).

Second your need create custom [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) for KeyValuePair<string,int> like this:

```
  public class PairConverter : JsonConverter
  {
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
       return objectType == typeof(KeyValuePair<string, int>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      var item = (KeyValuePair<string, int>)value;
      writer.WriteValue(item.Value);
      writer.Flush();
    }
  }
```

And than add JsonConverter attribute for 'Age' property like this:

```
 public class Persons
 {
   [JsonConverter(typeof(PairConverter))]
   public KeyValuePair<string, int> Age { get; set; }
 }
```

Finally, example of usage:

```
 var persons = new Persons()
 {
    Age = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Age", 10)
 };
 var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persons); // {Age:10}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking - code sample was quite handy.

Comment: Updated Newtonsoft links for [JsonConverter Class](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) and [Custom JsonConverter sample](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).