# C# custom json serialization

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

This class

```
class X{
    public string a{get;set}
    public string b{get;set}
}
```

is serialized like

```
{..., inst:{a:"value", b:"value"}, ...}
```

I need object of my class to be serialized like this:

```
{..., inst: x, ...}
```

Where x is a+b
How can I customize JSON serialization process from my class?

Comment: Most people finding this Q&A will want to customize the Newtonsoft JSON serialization process, outputting valid JSON that is different than a serialization of all public properties. (OP's output does not appear to be valid JSON, because value `x` isn't quoted - in that case, can't use this technique.) Simple changes, such as hiding an attribute, can be done using [JSON Serialization Attributes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm). More complex changes require [writing custom JsonConverter per class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4548916/199364).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout Newton-softs JSON serializer.  Its pretty sweet.

Have you tried making a and b private, and then have something like

```
public string x { get { return a + b; } }
```

Comment: Great idea about sum-property, but I deserialize this object from database first so I need these field to be public. So I will use Newton library, unfortunately there is no solutions from the box.

Comment: Consider using dedicated classes for your persistence model and viewmodel (or whatever it is you're serializing to Json). I find this is the easiest way to avoid problems like these. If the mapping between models becomes too complex, consider using automapper to manage it.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
class X{
    public string a{private get;set;}
    public string b{private get;set;}
    public string x {get{ return a + b; }}
}
```

Having a private get removes it from serialization but still allows it to be set.  The other option is to do it like this.

```
class X{
    public string a{set;}
    public string b{set;}
    public string x {get{ return a + b; }}
}
```