# retaining value of dynamically added textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I am dynamically added textboxes through code behind on button click and it is working fine. On another button click I want to get the values all the dynamically added textbox. But the value of the textboxes is empty. How to retain the value of the dynamically added textbox on postback?

Aspx code

```
<asp:Table runat="server" id="placeAddTds">
  <asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="txt_from" runat="server" class="sabsw" TabIndex="88"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="txt_to" runat="server" class="sabsw" TabIndex="89"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="txt_per" runat="server" class="sabsw" TabIndex="90"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>

    <asp:TableCell>
    <asp:Button class="main-btn add-btn pointer" runat="server" ID="btn_add" Text="Add" OnClick="TdsAddClick" TabIndex="91"></asp:Button>
   </asp:TableCell>
  </asp:TableRow>
  </asp:Table>
```

Code behind:

```
 protected void TdsAddClick(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            TextBox[] l1 = new TextBox[txtcount];
            TextBox[] l2 = new TextBox[txtcount];
            TextBox[] l3 = new TextBox[txtcount];
            for (int j = 1; j < txtcount; j++)
            {
                l1[j] = new TextBox();
                l2[j] = new TextBox();
                l3[j] = new TextBox();
                l1[j].ID = "txt_from" + j;
                l1[j].Attributes.Add("class","sabsw");
                l2[j].ID = "txt_to" + j;
                l2[j].Attributes.Add("class", "sabsw");
                l3[j].ID = "txt_per" + j;
                l3[j].Attributes.Add("class", "sabsw");
                placeAddTds.Rows.Add(new TableRow());
                placeAddTds.Rows[j].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                placeAddTds.Rows[j].Cells[0].Controls.Add(l1[j]);
                placeAddTds.Rows[j].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                placeAddTds.Rows[j].Cells[1].Controls.Add(l2[j]);
                placeAddTds.Rows[j].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                placeAddTds.Rows[j].Cells[2].Controls.Add(l3[j]);
           }
            txtcount++;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Well you have to recreate them on every postback and get the values from the Form collection

Comment: I think it is being created on every postback. But I don't know how to get the values of the dynamically created textbox on the button click of another button.

Comment: I think this is not a good approach, if you post your req, SO can able to provide a good approach than this.

Comment: I have two buttons. On click of one button I want to add textboxes dynamically and on click of the second button I want to save the value of all the textboxes in the database.

Comment: Just have a look at the **way** to avoid the postback.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is his **Requirement** from your comment.

**I have two buttons. On click of one button I want to add textboxes dynamically and on click of the second button I want to save the value of all the textboxes in the database**

You have 2 buttons 
One button you can create TextBox using Jquery. (Client Side script is very much faster while comparing with postbacks).

[*Here you can see how to add text box using Jquery*](http://jsfiddle.net/u9hvp/)

So you can add textbox dynamically without postback.

[*Another button you can serialize the form using Jquery and send it to server.*](http://jsfiddle.net/sxGtM/3/)

**Pass Data to Server**
It will create a JSON Object and pass it to server. 
You can pass in __doPostBack(control,args). In args you can pass the JSON Value.
[Click Here](http://joinwind.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/understanding-the-javascript-__dopostback-function-passing-arguments/)

**Process the JSON Data**

[C# JSON custom serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547550/c-sharp-json-custom-serialization)
This will show how to get data from JSON .

This is an approach which can be implemented with client side scripting and which may works much faster than the method you suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property with ViewState for this in your code-behind and store all values in a list:

```
private List<string> TextBoxValue
        {
            get
            {
                return (List<string>)ViewState["TextBoxValue"];
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["TextBoxValue"] = value;
            }
        }
```

You can then store the values of textboxes in this property. example:

```
TextBoxValue.Add(textBox1.Text);
```

However, this will make page heavy.

Comment: I think this approach will eat the time when you do every post back. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Can u suggest a better solution?

Comment: @VeeKeyBee: Yes it does, but only when your list has huge amount of records.