# Serialize a Dictionary as JSON object using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json, serialization, dictionary

I have an `[DataContract]` object that has some properties and is serialized to JSON using `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

One of the properties is of type `Dictionary<string, string>` and when the serialization happens it produces the following JSON schema.

```
"extra_data": [
  {
    "Key": "aKey",
    "Value": "aValue"
  }
]
```

Now I need the JSON schema to be like this

```
"extra_data": { 
        "aKey": "aValue"
}
```

You can never of course know before what the values are, it is a `Dictionary` that the user will set keys and values.

I'm thinking if this can happen using anonymous types, or is there a configuration I can take to accomplish my goal?

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547550/c-sharp-json-custom-serialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, let say you have:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "extra_data")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> MyDictionary { get; set; } 

}
```

Then you can use `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings` with `UseSimpleDictionaryFormat` set to true, something like this:

```
    var myObject = new MyObject { MyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "key1", "value1" }, { "key2", "value2" } } };

    DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings { UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true };

    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyObject), settings);

    var result = string.Empty;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(ms, myObject);

        result = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: Worked perfect and simple. Thank you.

Comment: For Windows Phone 8 I used the Newtonsoft JSON serializer Nuget package. http://james.newtonking.com/json

Comment: I dont have DataContractJsonSerializerSettings at all (running .NET 4.5), it just doest exist.

Comment: Hi, where can I replace the "normal" serializer with this serializier when I am create the service host in code?

Comment: DataContractJsonSerializerSettings is not available in .NET 4.0