# Hiding C# properties when serialize with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serialization, properties, json.net

How can we hide the C# property where serializing with JSON.NET library. Suppose, we have class Customer

```
public class Customer
{
   public int CustId {get; set;}
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}
   public bool isLocked {get; set;}
   public Customer() {}

}

public class Test
{
  Customer cust = new Customer();
  cust.CustId = 101;
  cust.FirstName = "John"
  cust.LastName = "Murphy"

  string Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cust); 
}
```

JSON

```
{   
    "CustId": 101,   
    "FirstName": "John",   
    "LastName": "Murphy",  
    "isLocked": false 
}
```

This object is converted to json, but i didn't specify the isLocked property. As library will serialize the entire class, is there any way to ignore a property during json serialization process or if we can add any attribute on the property.

**EDIT**:
Also, If we create two instance of Customer class in an array. if we didn't specify is locked property on the second instance, can we can property hide for second object.

JSON

```
{
  "Customer": [
    {
      "CustId": 101,
      "FirstName": "John",
      "LastName": "Murphy",
      "isLocked": false
    },
    {
      "CustId": 102,
      "FirstName": "Sara",
      "LastName": "connie"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 33):

Use the JSON.Net attributes:

```
public class Customer
{
   public int CustId {get; set;}
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}
   [JsonIgnore]
   public bool isLocked {get; set;}
   public Customer() {}

}
```

For more information: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm

Answer (score 12):

Yes, marking your properties with `JsonIgnore` is probably best.

However, if you do want to chose at runtime, add a `public bool ShouldSerialize{MemberName}` to your class. When JSON.net Serialises it will call it, and if false, not serialise. `isLocked` is false by default, perhaps you do want to serialise it when its true, for example.

Comment: If you're easy on which tools to use, Javascriptserializer offers a neater, more linq-y way of deciding what to serialise at runtime. Like this: `string jsonString = serializer.Serialize(customers.Select(x => x.CustId));` to only serialise `CustId`.

Comment: can you give simple example or link if there is any?

Comment: http://blog.mariusschulz.com/2013/04/15/conditionally-serializing-fields-and-properties-with-jsonnet

Comment: @A.P.S - [JavaScriptSerializer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8).  To be clear: that is an *alternative* approach. Before using javascriptserializer, I would investigate: newtonsoft's [JSON Serialization Attributes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm) and [JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4548916/199364), as well as above mentioned `ShouldSerialize`.

Answer (score 3):

Mark that property with the [`JsonIgnore`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm) attribute.